# inverse laplace transform of $ \frac{s^2 +1}{s^2+s-2} {e^{-2s}}$

Tags: laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

inverse laplace transform of $$ \frac{s^2 +1}{s^2+s-2} {e^{-2s}}$$

I tried solving it like that, but I'm not sure:

1- Apply partial fraction to the f(t) part:  $$(\frac{2/3}{s-1} + \frac{-5/3}{s+2}) {e^{-2s}}$$

2.Do the inverse transform and the first shift: $${2/3}{e^{s+2}} + {-5/3}{e^{-2{s+2}}}$$

Is this correct ?

Comment: Shouldn't the partial fractions result be $$e^{-2 s}\left(-\dfrac{5}{3 (s+2)}+\dfrac{2}{3 (s-1)}+1\right)$$

Comment: why the + 1 tho ?. I think ${s^2+s-2}$  can be broken into ${(s-1)}{(s+2)}$ and I could get the constants using the cover-up method ?

Comment: Find a common denominator with my result and see if you can combine the partial fractions.